# :: versus . for member functions (C++)

Tags: c++, oop

I know that, given a class, say, std::array, which has a member function, say, size(), we can call on that member function via a ".", that is, in the following code,

```
array<int,5> myarray;
int s=myarray.size();
```

s would be the integer representing the size of myarray. The tricky thing happens when member functions can also be called by the namespace operator "::". For example, I know that the following line of code is valid:

```
auto t=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

Then, what's wrong with employing the syntax we originally used with array?

```
chrono::high_resolution_clock myclock;
auto t=myclock.now();
```

Comment: you have to read about `static member functions`.

Comment: `now()` is a static member function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723143/c-static-member-functions

Comment: thanks! that will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`now()` is a `static` member function. This means that the function itself doesn't have a hidden `this` pointer. Instead, it's just like a regular function - just part of the class to avoid name collisions.

(THe `high_resolution_clock` is a class, `chrono` is a namespace, in your example. Both use `::` to indicate "I want something from inside {namespace, class})

Comment: Perhaps this raises another question: in the particular case of `std::array<T, Size>`, why is `size()` *not* a static member function?

Comment: Because the designers of STL want it to be orthogonal with `std::vector` for example.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, `::` separates names from surnames, while `.` separates components from sub-components. (Note that in many languages like C#, Java, D, ...) there is no such distinction)

In your fist example, `myarray` is a variable, whose `size()` method refer to that particular variable.

```
array<int,5> myarray_a, myarray_b;
int sa=myarray_a.size();
int sb=myarray_b.size();
```

Will give the sizes of `myarray_a` and `b` respectively (not of `array<int,5>`, even if -due to this particular case- all sizes will be 5)

In the second example, now() is a `static` method of the class `chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

It doesn't matter if you have or not a variable (and how many) of type `chrono::high_resolution_clock`. That function does not refer to the variable but works the same for all variables of the same type (there is conceptually just one `now`, no matter who you ask to).

Because of this, call `now()` as part of a variable, of by fully qualifying its name is the same.

Note that, the `size()` function of `std::array` is *strange*: the size of `std::array` is compile time defined, hence `size()` could have been static as well. But `std::` designers let them as member (although `constexpr`, so still usable in compile time expressions) to retain the same behavior as in `std::array` or other containers (where it has to be dynamic, and associated to a variable, since each size can vary during execution)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up 2 concepts here:
"::" is used for namespaces, but also for calling **static** methods.

Comment: C++ is mixing up two concepts here :-p

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing *wrong* with the syntax you suggested. It works.

However it creates an object, whereas the `::` version does not create any object.  There doesn't seem to be much point in creating that object since it is not necessary to do so in order to call the static function. So it is simpler to just call the static function without creating the object.

Comment: This is great. thanks! I actually prefer this redundancy, cause I am at a learning stage at this point.

Comment: "It creates an object"? Really? Do you have a source for that? How would it do so, which ctor?

Comment: @MSalters if `X` is a class, then `X x;` (in a function or at namespace scope) creates an object `x` of type `X`. Do you really need a standard reference for that?

Comment: [See it working](http://ideone.com/Ow3Ecw). If no arguments are provided then the default constructor is used.

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer. I took it as `.` creates an object, which was a bit puzzling.